# MySQL cannot find data file for a load operation

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, load-data-infile

I would like to load a data file into MySQL using the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/David/Desktop/popularity20110511/test_data' INTO TABLE test_table
```

The above command gives me the following error:

```
#7890 - Can't find file '/Users/David/Desktop/popularity20110511/test_data'.
```

I've also tried:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/David/Desktop/popularity20110511/test_data' INTO TABLE test_table
```

I also gives me an error:

```
#13 - Can't get stat of '/Users/David/Desktop/popularity20110511/test_data' (Errcode: 13)
```

I've repeatedly checked the file path and name and I've also made sure the file privilege is set to `Read & Write` for everyone.

I am using a Mac and phpMyAdmin.

Any suggestions on what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure what the problem is but I made it work by moving the file to `/tmp/test_data` and used `LOAD DATA INFILE...`

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue.  Maybe the file permissions were correct and the folder wasn't?

Comment: I just re-checked the folder permissions and made sure it was`Read & Write` but that didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem using MacOs and tried to change permissions, etc, but I realized you have to use the same directory structure you have using in the Terminal Application. Example: if you have `(localhost/myproject/myfile.csv)` try using

```
(Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/myproject/myfile.csv).
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/myproject/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE `mytable` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue, trying to import an SQL file that uses     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE... to import a CSV file in phpMyAdmin and got the same error message:
    #7890 - Can't find file 'myfile.csv'

The solution I found was to put the file in the same folder as phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem

'C:/Program Files/DatabaseTableHolders/Menu.csv'

## 7890 - Can't find file '

The first thing I did was move the files to the "Program File" directory
It still wouldn't work

Then I changed the path address from

'C:/Program Files/DatabaseTableHolders/Menu.csv'

to

'C:\Program Files\DatabaseTableHolders\Menu.csv'

THIS WORKS!!!
For me its something to do with the path structure.

By the way I'm using Eclipse and phpMyAdmin on WAMP  (windows operating system). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I meet the same error.
My situation:
XAMPP + MAC OS 10.9

```
load data local infile '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jsonSQL.txt' into table `ttlegs` fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
```

and this works when I put jsonSQL.txt to htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you put that text file in 'xammp /phpMyAdmin ' directory ( I assume you work on xammp)  That's it.  then LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE will work.  Happy Coding